# JSLint Error: Weird Relation while comparing strings

Tags: jslint

Is there is a way to compare strings in JSLint?

I have written the following code which is evaluated by JSLint:

```
if(('SIVA') === 'SIVA'){
    Result = 1000;
    return;
}
```

The above code works for javascript but I am getting the following error when evaluated by JSLint:  "Weird Relation"

How to rectify this issue?

Comment: What version of JSLint. When I make an example in jsfiddle an try JSHint (which utilizes JSLint, I guess), I get no trouble: http://jsfiddle.net/fK7rw/1/

Comment: http://jslinterrors.com/weird-relation/

Comment: I am using the current version of JSLint .I tested it in www.jslint.com,but I get the same error there too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ..issue is fixed.Removed weird_relation property and removed the property in warn() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution might be quite easy.

Your backend code is writing a string into JavaScript, right?  So instead of this:

```
if( ( 'SIVA' ) === 'SIVA' ) {
  result_int = 1000;
  return;
}
```

Which on the backend looks like this:

```
if( ( '<%key_code%>' ) === 'SIVA' ) {
  result_int = 1000;
  return;
}
```

Do this on the backend template:

```
var key_code = '<%key_code%>';

if( key_code === 'SIVA' ) {
  result_int = 1000;
  return;
}
```

Which will be filled out on the client as such:

```
var key_code = 'SIVA';

if( key_code === 'SIVA' ) {
  result_int = 1000;
  return;
}
```

Both the template and the code delivered to the client should pass JSLint.

Comment: @JavaUser is this what you are looking for, or is there something else?  Better yet, if this has solved your problem, could you please mark it as a solution?

Comment: Ah, good call. I mean, there's still a *huge* problem -- if OP is really using code like `if( ( '<%key_code%>' ) === 'SIVA' ) {` and not handling that comparison to a static value on the server instead, I kind of feel we've already lost him or her (that's a gross misuse of dynamically generated JavaScript), but I'm glad you were able to see through my mental block there. ;^)

Comment: @ruffin, you are correct: generally this is a few too many levels of abstraction for sanity.  Better to avoid generated JS if one can :)

Answer (score 1):

Not real sure what you're trying to do here.  You're comparing a static string to a static string with `('SIVA') === 'SIVA'`, which gives a weird relation.

**If you compare `'SIVA'` to `'SIVA'`, it'll always be true.  Why use an `if` to see if true is true?  That's weird! That's the reason JSLint reports "Weird condition".  ;^)**

I'm assuming you wanted one of those SIVAs to be a variable, which I change in the code below.

Here's code similar to what I think you're doing that passes JSLint.

```
/*jslint sloppy:true, white:true, browser:true */
var Result, sivaValueToCheck;

if(sivaValueToCheck === 'SIVA'){
    Result = 1000;
    // return;  // don't exit early.  configure your else.
}    else    {
    window.alert('do the logic you wanted to skip before');
}
```

Note that you have to declare `Result` and you can't simply `return` if you want to pass JSLint.  You can debate the usefulness of the single return rule, but the idea is that a single return makes for easier to follow code.

Comment: The one within parenthesis is not static string .It comes from backend.I am using this condition to check the value from the table with the one which is provided from the user

Comment: Then you need to let us see your actual code.  `('SIVA')` as written in your question clearly evaluates to a static string -- and I bet it's causing your JSLint error. But I suspect from this and your other recent question you might be expecting different behavior. Either what you have in your question *is* your code, and that *is* what's causing the JSLint error, or you need to let us see the "real" thing.  ;^)

Comment: @ ruffin The condition which I have mentioned is generated dynamically based on user selection,but it is not actual java code.This condition is passed to  jslint for evaluation and is working fine for all the operators except this because of weird_relation property in jslint.js.So I removed this property and the issue is fixed.

Comment: Do you want to show us your code, even if just in *your* "answer", to show how that's any different than what's above? Are you saying that you're using Java to dynamically create JavaScript code? I'm afraid this is not a well-worded question, and your answer just restates what I have above. How did you "generate dynamically" the code in your question? That's probably^H^H^H important.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript accepts if('a'== 'a') but JSLint doesn't allow it due to weird_relation property. If  weird_relation property is removed from messages and if it is removed from the method where it is used, it won't show any error.I did that and it started working.